# in app purchase vs Paypal for developer

Tags: ios, paypal, in-app-purchase

I was considering to implement a payment method in my iOS app.
I considered to use IAP (In App Purchase) or PayPal. IAP is actually very expensive, Apple charges up to 40% according with the country you belong. On the other hand PayPal charges you something like 3% - 4%.
Anyone knows why the gap is so huge? 
Does PayPal breaks Apple purchasing terms?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The gap is huge, because Apple brings you the end user directly, by using it's tools, platforms and market, whereas, PayPal is just a payment system, which does almost nothing for you.

In this case, you should consider the Apple just like your agent selling your house, who searches for customers, advertises, does all the documentation s**t, sells and gets his percent from the sale. So, Apple is getting it's 30% for using it's ecosystem, not for the payment only.

And, no, I don't think PayPal breaks Apple's purchasing terms.

PS: I don't work for Apple ))

Comment: Well if I implement IAP inside my app for "premium profile" purpose I don't get any "selling agent" advantage. Maybe IAP is easier to implement and more user friendly.
I don't see any other advantage....?!?